# Order of threads in execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Consider this simple concurrence example :

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex

std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

void print_block(int n, char c) {
    // critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
    mtx.lock();
    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i) { std::cout << c; }
    std::cout << '\n';
    mtx.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th1(print_block, 50, '*');
    std::thread th2(print_block, 50, '$');

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Is it always guaranteed that `th1` will be the first thread to execute the for loop ?

Meaning , when I do this :

```
th1.join();
th2.join();
```

Then can I be absolutely sure that `th1` will be executed first and then `th2` ?

Comment: When dealing with concurrent programming, never make any hypothesis about order of execution. On the opposite, assume that all situations are possible. This makes your code more reliable and, paradoxically, simpler.

Comment: [You are using `std::mutex` wrong](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#locking-mutex), ,you should never call `std::mutex::lock()` and `std::mutex::unlock()`. Instead create a `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` at the start of `print_block()` and let it lock and unlock the mutex for you.

Comment: Normally, we don't care who goes first, we care about who finishes first, that's why we have the function `join`. In your example, `th1` will goes first because you put `th1` before `th2` in the `main`.

Comment: use conditional variable may achieve what you want to do, but what's the point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you're most likely seeing `th1` always start first because thread construction for that variable is done first (and thread construction is expensive), thus `th2` starts after. This doesn't mean that there's an order.

Calling `join()` does not have anything to do with which thread gets executed first, that's done at construction when you provide a callable.

`th1` can be constructed and then stalled by the OS, which would then cause `th2` to run first. There is no order unless you implement one.

Consider this example that gives a much fairer start to both threads, it sometimes outputs thread 1 as being the first to acquire the lock, it sometimes outputs thread 2.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>         // std::cout
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <unordered_map>    // std::unordered_map<K, V>
#include <thread>           // std::thread
#include <mutex>            // std::mutex
#include <atomic>           // std::atomic<T>

std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, std::string> thread_map;
std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section
std::atomic<bool> go{ false };

void print_block( int n, char c )
{
    while ( !go ) {} // prevent threads from executing until go is set.
    // critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
    mtx.lock();

    std::cout << thread_map.find( std::this_thread::get_id() )->second <<
        " acquires the lock.\n";

    mtx.unlock();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th1( print_block, 50, '*' );
    std::thread th2( print_block, 50, '$' );

    thread_map.emplace( std::make_pair( th1.get_id(), "Thread 1" ) );
    thread_map.emplace( std::make_pair( th2.get_id(), "Thread 2" ) );

    go.store( true );

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But in my example , why is the order always the same ? first `th1` and then `th2` ? Even when I replaced the lines one with the other , the order stayed the same . Only when I replaced the construction , the order changed .

Comment: @ron When you replaced which lines with each other? If you mean the calls to `join()`, that's because `join()` has nothing to do with the order in which threads start executing. I explained why constructing one thread first usually makes it start before the other.

Comment: OK , let me see if I got you : both threads reach the while loop (`while (!go) {}`) and then the Main thread flips on the `go` flag , and only then there is a race condition to acquire the lock ?

Comment: @ron There is no race condition on acquiring locks, locks are thread safe. If you literally mean that both threads will then race to acquire a lock, then yes; That's why it's fairer. We wait until both threads have finished their construction and only then do we let them fight for the lock. If you execute my example, you will see that sometimes thread 2 acquires the lock before thread 1.