# How does joining threads affect the order of execution in the main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I know that threads run concurrently so you can't predict the order of execution but in the provided code, I joined thread `t4` before running anything else. if `.join()` is supposed to wait until the thread is finished executing, then why is the order still random? joining anything before the two print statements will always cause them to be printed last whereas if I join everything afterwards, it's not always last, why?

```
void task() {
    std::cout << "task 1 says Hi\n";
}
void task2() {
    std::cout << "task 2 says Hi\n";
}
void task3() {
    std::cout << "task 3 says Hi\n";
}
void task4() {
    std::cout << "task 4 says Hi\n";
}
int main() {
    std::thread t1(task);
    std::thread t2(task2);
    std::thread t3(task3);
    std::thread t4(task4);

    t4.join();
    std::cout << "main says Hi 1\n";
    // synchronize - IMPORTANT!
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t1.join();
    std::cout << "main says Hi 2" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This might help you to get explanation! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933811/order-of-threads-in-execution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of threads in execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933811/order-of-threads-in-execution)

Answer (score 4):

[`std::thread::join`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) only blocks the current thread until the thread identified by `*this` finishes its execution.

So what this assures you is that `main says Hi 1` will not be printed before `task 4 says Hi` and that `main says Hi 2` is not printed before the other three tasks have finished execution.

The `printf` statements in the four tasks can be printed in any order and it is also possible that output from different threads may interleave.

Comment: Note that those tasks prints may be even interleaved, since IIRC the Standard does not guarantee any multi-threaded synchronization for output streams. Namely, it just guarantees that data races won't occur: http://eel.is/c++draft/iostream.objects#overview-5.

Comment: I am not quite sure about your last note. If line buffering is enabled, the output should not interleave character by character, but just line by line, no? But I am not quite sure if the line buffer is thread local, so maybe you are right.

Comment: @dizzyflames: does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

As you start your threads on creation, the threads will most probably execute their code before you join them. You create `t1` first, `t1` most probably will execute first and then all others in the other you created them.

A `join` an your `t4` will not guarantee that it executes before `t1` or any other thread you create. It simply waits for the termination of `t4`.

Quick test in Visual Studio shows:

```
task 4 says Hi
task 2 says Hi
task 3 says Hi
task 2 says Hi
main says Hi 1
main says Hi 2
```

with following code (snippet):

```
// ...
std::thread t4(task2);
std::thread t2(task2);
std::thread t3(task3);
std::thread t2(task2);
// ...
```

Comment: as his `join` for `t4` is called before `join` for `t1`, pretty sure `t4` is guaranteed to execute before `t1`.

Comment: `join` does not mess with the scheduler. so you can't make a reliable prediction whether `t1` executes first or any other thread. since he creates `t1` first, `t1` is most likely to execute first, but not for sure. `join(t4)` simply waits on `t4`s termination, nothing more. the thread scheduler determines which thread comes first not you with a `join` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The termination of the joined thread *synchronizes-with* the end of the `join()` in the joining thread. Simply put, this means everything that happens in the joining thread *after* the `join()` is also guaranteed to happen *after* everything that happened in the joined thread. There are a few places in the C++ standard that establish strong synchronizes-with relationships of this kind (e.g. an atomic store in one thread with memory order `std::memory_order_seq_cst` synchronizes-with an atomic load on another thread *if* the value loaded is the one stored in the first thread). There are also some weaker guarantees given, e.g. for atomic accesses with weaker memory orders.

You can think about the resulting execution as one of the possible results of performing a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the directed acyclic graph that results from these synchronizes-with relationships. (If the graph is ever cyclic, then you have a deadlock.)

Specifically, no guarantees are given for the relative order of operations if no synchronizes-with path exists from either of them to the other. You **cannot** traverse edges backwards, but this appears to be how you expect things to work out. Just because the main thread joins thread 4 before thread 1, it does not mean that *anything* on thread 4 happens-before *anything* on thread 1. For this to hold true, you would need to introduce an additional edge into the DAG or reorder operations to make this true (that is, provable). E.g. you could start thread 1, from the main thread, only after the join of thread 4 – *then*, anything that happens in thread 1 will happen after everything that happens in thread 4 because thread creation synchronizes-with the beginning of the new thread, which then establishes a transitive dependency that looks like this:

- Thread 4 performs some output.
- … this happens-before thread 4 terminates (note that this deduction is only valid because both events are on the same thread).
- … this synchronizes-with `thread4.join()` on the main thread.
- … this happens-before the creation of `thread1` on the main thread (again, only because it is the same thread).
- … this synchronizes-with all operations that happen on `thread1`.
- … including any output that is performed on thread 1.

TL;DR: Thread synchronization in principle is a one-way street. It is like flushing buffers (in fact, it may involve flushing the so-called store buffers on the hardware level): It guarantees that all previous writes have finished, but it does not delay any previous writes in any form. If you need stricter guarantees, you must use different means of synchronization.